# Atualizar list view após áudio

Tags: java, android

Estou tentando atualizar minha lista de músicas quando gravo um áudio, mas não está funcionando.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button mRecordBtn;
private Button mAtualizarBtn;
private TextView mRecordLabel;
private MediaRecorder mRecorder;
private String mFileName = null;
private static final String LOG_TAG = "Record_log";
//private StorageReference mStorage;
private ProgressDialog mProgress;

ListView lv;
String[] items;
FetchSongs fs;
ArrayList<File> mySongs;
ProgressDialog dialog;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    fs = new FetchSongs();
    dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    dialog.setMessage("Please wait, Fetching Songs...");
    dialog.setCancelable(true);
    dialog.show();


    while (fs.getfetchstatus() != true) {
        mySongs = fs.findSongs(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());

    }
    if (mySongs != null) {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }

    mySongs = fs.getsonglist();

    items = new String[mySongs.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < mySongs.size(); i++) {
        items[i] = mySongs.get(i).getName().toString().replace(".3gp", "");


    }


    final ArrayAdapter<String> adp = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
    lv.setAdapter(adp);
    adp.notifyDataSetChanged();
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Player.class);
            intent.putExtra("pos", i);
            adp.notifyDataSetChanged();

            startActivity(intent);
            finish();

        }
    });


    mAtualizarBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.atualizarBtn);
    mRecordLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.recordLabel);
    mRecordBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.recordBtn);

    mProgress = new ProgressDialog(this);
    //mFileName = getExternalCacheDir().getAbsolutePath();

    Long tsLong = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;
    String ts = tsLong.toString();
    mFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/recording-"+ts+".mp3";
    adp.notifyDataSetChanged();

    lv.setAdapter(adp);
    adp.notifyDataSetChanged();
    //mFileName += "/record_audio.MP3";

    mRecordBtn.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent)
        {

            if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

                startRecording();
                mRecordLabel.setText("GRAVANDO");
                adp.notifyDataSetChanged();


            } else if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {


                stopRecording();
                mRecordLabel.setText("Feche o app para " +
                        "atualizar a lista");


                lv.setAdapter(adp);
                adp.notifyDataSetChanged();



            }

            return false;
        }


    });
}

private void startRecording()
{


    Long tsLong = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;
    String ts = tsLong.toString();


    mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.DEFAULT);
    mRecorder.setOutputFile(mFileName);
    mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
    mFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/recording-"+ts+".mp3";

    try
    {
        mRecorder.prepare();

    } catch (IOException e)
    {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "prepare() failed");
    }

    mRecorder.start();

}

private void stopRecording()
{

    mRecorder.stop();
    mRecorder.release();
    mRecorder = null;

}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

After recording file, you're not updating your items array which is the data source of your adapter.

Depois de gravar um arquivo, você não está atualizando o seu array de itens que é a fonte de dados do seu Adapter.